# how to print ipdata language name using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I need to know how to print the language name in ipdata
I have this code at the bottom working well and the results appear correct but when I get the name of the language the results show the language name = undefined;

results

```
184.23.215.250
United States
<img src="https://ipdata.co/flags/us.png">
US
North America
Sonic Telecom LLC
undefined
```

my js vars is

```
var country_name = response.country_name;
var flag = response.flag;
var country_code = response.country_code;
var continent_name = response.continent_name;
var organisation = response.organisation;
var lang = response.languages.name;
```

you can try it from http://tiger222.atwebpages.com/set.php

You will find the data correct but, how do I get the language name correctly ?

`var lang = response.languages->name;` this is not working 

`var lang = response.languages.name;` and this is not working

Comment: did you try `response.languages[0].name;`

Comment: thanks bro, that's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source data, `languages` is an **[array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)**, e.g.

```
"languages": [
    {
        "name": "English",
        "native": "English"
    }
],
```

Therefore it can potentially contain multiple entries.

Assuming you just want the first language in the list, then you can address the first index of the array directly, like this:

```
var lang = response.languages[0].name;
```

---

P.S. `->` is not valid syntax in JavaScript. You were perhaps thinking of PHP syntax there.

Comment: `var lang = response.languages[0].name;` is working ,thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

This is array

```
var lang = response.languages[0].name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Languages is an array so you would have to map on its elements and get name out of it.

```
"languages": [
    {
        "name": "English",
        "native": "English"
    }
],
```

It may break if there are no languages in the array so you can do defensive code like below:

```
var lang = (response.languages && response.languages.length && response.languages[0].name) || '';
```

```js
const response = {
    "ip": "12.00.00.01",
    "is_eu": false,
    "city": "Any City",
    "region": "Pennsylvania",
    "region_code": "PA",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "country_code": "US",
    "continent_name": "North America",
    "continent_code": "NA",
    "latitude": 49.9776,
    "longitude": -95.3099,
    "asn": "AS7018",
    "organisation": "AT&T Services, Inc.",
    "postal": "18083",
    "calling_code": "1",
    "flag": "https://ipdata.co/flags/us.png",
    "emoji_flag": "\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8",
    "emoji_unicode": "U+1F1FA U+1F1F8",
    "carrier": {
        "name": "AT&T",
        "mcc": "310",
        "mnc": "016"
    },
    "languages": [
        {
            "name": "English",
            "native": "English"
        }
    ],
    "currency": {
        "name": "US Dollar",
        "code": "USD",
        "symbol": "$",
        "native": "$",
        "plural": "US dollars"
    },
    "time_zone": {
        "name": "America/New_York",
        "abbr": "EDT",
        "offset": "-0400",
        "is_dst": true,
        "current_time": "2019-05-30T08:52:43.569643-04:00"
    },
    "threat": {
        "is_tor": false,
        "is_proxy": false,
        "is_anonymous": false,
        "is_known_attacker": false,
        "is_known_abuser": false,
        "is_threat": false,
        "is_bogon": false
    },
    "count": "1501"
};
var country_name = response.country_name;
var flag = response.flag;
var country_code = response.country_code;
var continent_name = response.continent_name;
var organisation = response.organisation;
var lang = response.languages[0].name;

console.log(lang);
```